# Swift (Xcode), separate style on one label text

Tags: xcode, swift

Is it possible to stylize one label with different styles, for example:

"Welcome home, Name", I would like Name to have a different color and font-style such as italics.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[`NSAttributedString` or `NSMutableAttributedString`](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSAttributedString_Class/) are what you're looking for.

You can set attributes like font, size, color, background color and style for individual characters within a string.

[This site](https://makeapppie.com/2014/10/20/swift-swift-using-attributed-strings-in-swift/) provides a solid tutorial on `NSAttributedString` use in Swift.